# How to list children with a specific name?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

I have a movieclip that have multiple objects with the same name and I want to access the top most child with a specific name - how would I go about this?  I know

```
mc.getChildByName('theName')
```

returns the first child of that name, but I actually need to get the top most child.

Comment: You shouldn't have more than one instance variable on a Class by the same name (which is what will happen if you name more than one instance the same thing). What's the underlying goal?

Comment: yeah, I am realizing that now, too far into the project to really fix it now...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way would be :

```
function getTopChild(targetMC, childName:String):MovieClip
{
    for (var index:int = targetMC.numChildren-1;index >= 0;index--)
    {
        var child:MovieClip = targetMC.getChildAt(index) as MovieClip;
        if (child.name == childName)
        {
            return child;
        }
    }
    return null;
}
```

Comment: thanks but i am getting an error when I try to test, Function does not return a value - any thoughts?

Comment: I edited for it to return null, that is in the case that the childName doesn't exist. But, what is the exact error you are getting ?

Comment: It looks like you've probably modified the provided code so that it's possible for the code to go down a path without a return statement.

Comment: @prototypical I will try it again with the updated "return null" rather than just "return"

Comment: thanks @prototypical that worked great! - I was getting the error before because there was a chance there wasn't a child with that name.